# Mongodb - Query Array of Objects, but only return one property

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I don't think this is a duplicate, but please correct me if I'm wrong. Anyway, I would like to return only "apple" and the customer member role that matches the user's object email address. I am using $elemMatch, but that returns the whole customer object, I only want the "member" property, that's it.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("54d24e5df2878d40192beabd"),
    "apple" : "yes",
    "orange" : "yes",
    "customers" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "Jay Smith",
            "email" : "jaysmith@example.com",
            "member" : "silver", 
        },
        {
            "name" : "Sarah Carter",
            "email" : "sarahcarter@example.com",
            "member" : "gold",
        },
        {
            "name" : "Jack Whatever",
            "email" : "jackwhatever@example.com",
            "member" : "gold",
        },
    ]
 }
```

Ideal result back would be:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("54d24e5df2878d40192beabd"),
    "apple" : "yes",
    "member" : "gold"
}
```

or even this would suffice:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("54d24e5df2878d40192beabd"),
    "apple" : "yes",
    "orange" : "yes",
    "customers" : [
         {"member" : "gold"}
    ]
}
```

This is currently what I have:

```
   ItemsModel.find({ _id: { $in: _.pluck(user.items, 'itemId') }, active: true},
       {apple: 1, customers: {$elemMatch: {email: user.email}} }, 
           function(error, items) {
               if (error) { return next(error); }

                req.payload = {};
                req.payload.items = items;
                next();
            });
```

Any help would be really appreciated. Is this even possible? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ItemsModel.aggregate([
  { $unwind: '$customers' },
  { $match: { _id: { $in: _.pluck(user.items, 'itemId'), 'customers.email': user.email } },
  { $project : { _id:1 , apple:1, member:'$customers.member' }}
], function(err, res){
  // rest of your code here
})
```

Will give you

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("54d24e5df2878d40192beabd"),
    "apple" : "yes",
    "member" : "gold"
}
```

Comment: I'm getting it as customers: ["member": "gold"], not as "member": "gold", but I'll still mark this as the correct answer. Genius stuff. Thank you!

Comment: Oops, should be member:'$customers.member'. I've modified my answer